# Convert VBA code to Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am using the below code in macro to delete blank rows in excel. Can you please help me in converting the same into Vbscript?

```
Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
   Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

waiting for your valuable response.

Answer (score 5):

VBScript doesn't provide implicit parent objects like the VBA runtime environment does, so you need to make everything explicit:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

ws.Columns("A:A").Select
...
```

Also, VBScript doesn't recognize VBA named constants, so you need to either use the numeric value:

```
...
xl.Selection.SpecialCells(4).Select
...
```

or define the constant in your script:

```
Const xlCellTypeBlanks = 4
...
xl.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
...
```

See [here](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) for more information about translating VBA to VBScript.