# Need VBS code to saveas xlsm

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have tried so many websites and combinations but I can not create a VBS script to open my CsV file and then save it as a Xlsm file. I did get it to rename the file but the renamed file was deemed corrupt and would not open.
In Excel you can open a CSV and do a save as Xlsm and it works. I want to automate this process with the sccript below. This is Excel 2013. 
Option Explicit

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\1Datadump\datadump.csv")
xlApp.Application.Visible = True


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\1Datadump\datadump.xlsm"
xlApp.Workbooks.close
xlApp.Application.Quit
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You may want to conside saving it as a .xlsx file extension (no reason for CSV file to be macro enabled) and to specifiy the second paramter (file format) as  integer 50 (version 12 - 2007)

Answer (score 1):

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29557401/603855) that/why

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\1Datadump\datadump.xlsm"
```

(:=, named parameter) is not valid VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `FileFormat`.  You'll also need to qualify your workbook reference:

If you want to save the `ActiveWorkbook` then use `Application.ActiveWorkbook`:

```
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\1Datadump\datadump.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

But since you already have a refernce to the workbook; I'd use:

```
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
xlBook.SaveAs "C:\1Datadump\datadump.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```