# Scripting Word from vbs

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I'm trying to get Word to fill in cells in a table. The script works when run as a macro from within Word, but fails when saved as a .vbs file and double-clicked, or run with wscript. This is a part of it.

```
set obj = GetObject(,"Word.Application)
With obj
    With .Selection
        MsgBox .text
        If (.Information(wdWithInTable) = True) Then

            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            tCols = .Tables(1).Columns.Count
            tRow = .Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)
            tCol = .Information(wdStartOfRangeColumnNumber)

            For I = 2 To 5
                .Tables(1).Cell(tRow, I).Range.Text = "fred" & Str(I)
            Next

            ` now make new row
            For I = 1 To tCols - tCol + 1
                .MoveRight unit:=wdCell
            Next

        End If
    End With
End With
```

I have three problems. First, it won't compile unless I comment out the `.Collapse` and `.MoveRight` lines. Second, although the `MsgBox .text` displays the selected text, I get "out of range" errors if I try to access any `.Information` property.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple: I usually write software for Macs, and I'd do this using AppleScript. This is my first attempt at getting anything done under Windows.

Comment: You [cannot use constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14122422/11683) such as `wdCollapseStart` in VBScript. Put Option Explicit on top and it will correctly stop compiling. Replace them with their literal value (e.g. `wdWithInTable` => `12`), or declare them as `Const`s with correct values in the beginning of your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert VBA code to Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927864/convert-vba-code-to-vbscript)

Comment: You'd think with the age of VBScript now that this wouldn't be the first time this has come up on [so] and you'd be right.

Comment: [Yet another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29557401/692942)

Comment: [Still another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14064069/692942) guess it should be expected.

Comment: Also, there is a quite clear typo in the first-line of the code, should be `Set obj = GetObject(,"Word.Application")`.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript and VBA are different languages.

They are a bit similar, but not very. Moreover, VBScript is *not* like AppleScript; it doesn't let you easily interface with running programs.

The interfaces you'll get from VBScript can behave subtly differently in VBA and VBScript. However, I think you've got two problems here:

- `:=` is invalid syntax in VBScript; you'll need to find an alternative way of calling the function. Try just using positional arguments.
- You've no guarantee that this will open the expected file; there could be another instance of Word that it's interacting with instead.

Comment: Also, might be good to use an vbs editor so you can compile/debug/code-complete/etc

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is not running within the Word environment it would require a *reference* to the Word object library in order to use *enumeration constants* (those things that start with `wd`).

VBScript, however, cannot work with references, which means the only possibility is to use the `long` value equivalents of the enumerations. You'll find these in the Word Language References. Simplest to use is probably the Object Browser in Word's VBA Editor. (In Word: Alt+F11 to open the VBA Editor; F2 to start the Object Browser; type in the term in the "Search" box, click on the term, then look in the bottom bar.)

The code in the question uses, for example:

```
wdWithInTable
wdCollapseStart
wdStartOfRangeRowNumber
wdStartOfRangeColumnNumber
wdCell
```

The reason you get various kinds of errors depends on where these are used.

Also, VBScript can't used named parameters such as `Unit:=`. Any parameters must be passed in comma-delimited format, if there's more than one, in the order specified by the method or property. If there are *optional* parameters you don't want to use these should be left "blank":

```
MethodName parameter, parameter, , , parameter
```